# What tools can diagnose C++ portability issues due to plain char signedness?

Tags: c++, c, char, static-analysis, tool-rec

We recently discovered a line of code that was doing the equivalent of

```
bool should_escape_control_char(char ch) {
    return (ch < 0x20);  // control chars are 0x00 through 0x1F
}
```

This works **if plain `char` is unsigned**; but if plain `char` is signed, then this filter accidentally catches negative chars as well. (The ultimate effect was that a naïve JSON encoder was encoding `"é"` as `"\u00c3\u00a9"` because to the encoder, it looked like a pair of negative chars which were then individually encoded.)

IMO, the original sin here is that we're comparing a plain `char` expression against an integer, in such a way that the result depends on the signedness of `char`. I wish the compiler had told us:

```
fantasy-warning: this comparison's result may depend on the signedness of plain char
    return (ch < 0x20);  // control chars are 0x00 through 0x1F
            ^~~~~~~~~
fantasy-note: cast the operand to silence this diagnostic
    return (ch < 0x20);  // control chars are 0x00 through 0x1F
            ~~
            (signed char)(ch)
```

I was surprised to discover that Clang gives no option to warn in this situation; and I don't see any warning option in GCC either.

- Am I just not looking in the right place?
- What tools / linters / static-analyzers exist that *do* warn in this situation?

Comment: If there were a compiler warning for this kind of situation, I believe it would emit more warnings than you could possibly imagine for completely legitimate code.  This is a straight-up coding bug.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not portable even if you changed it to

```
bool should_escape_control_char(unsigned char ch)
```

as you're still making assumptions about the character encoding on your platform. Use

```
int std::iscntrl( int ch );
```

instead, or the C equivalent depending on the language you're using.

Reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/iscntrl

(The C version is reachable from that site).

Comment: it is clear from the question that OP uses UTF-8-encoded chars. `iscntrl` is the wrong choice here. The set of values is fixed, and not dependent on whatever locale is used.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Methinks you should submit an answer. Ping me if you do.

Comment: I do not have solution to the problem. Your answer did not address the concern of the OP either.

Answer (score 1):

Static analysers that I use didn't diagnose the original example. Writing unit tests and compiling them with both unsigned and signed char could help catch bugs like this in automated testing stage.

---

When using unsigned numbers, it is safer to compare them with explicitly unsigned operands instead of letting signed operand be implicitly converted. So, given that char was assumed to be unsigned:

```
bool should_escape_control_char(char ch) {
    return ch < 0x20u;  // control chars are 0x00 through 0x1F
//                  ^
}
```

In this case, if the assumed signedness of char is wrong, (at least some?) compilers would warn about this when the char is signed and warnings are enabled:

```
warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'char' and 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-compare]
```

---

Instead of relying magic numbers, it would be better to use `std::iscntrl` from the standard library:

```
bool
is_control_c0(unsigned char ch) {
    return std::iscntrl(ch
        // provide locale if not using currently active
    );
}
```

---

Note that a function accepting a single narrow char - i.e. a code unit - cannot match all control code points in UTF-8 because C1 control codes are encoded as two code units.

Comment: Given "a naïve JSON encoder was encoding `"é"` as `"\u00c3\u00a9"`" from the question, I'm not certain that all the problems in that "naïve JSON encoder" can be fully addressed with `iscntrl()`.  I suspect there's a lot more issues, hence the desire for better compiler diagnostics.

Comment: " are technically encoding " -> "are encoding". I'm not sure there is anything "technically" about it.

Comment: @Bathsheba "technically" is there because there are *many* encodings where that assumption applies, and *many* use cases where one doesn't need to care about encodings where  it doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm asking for tools that warn on the original (buggy) code, not tools that *would* warn if the code had been written differently. If I had a time machine to go back and tell the programmer to write it differently, I would just tell them to add the cast in the first place.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Like I said in the answer: Unit tests. I simply showed a way of writing programs that is safer when making assumptions about signedness.

Comment: 1) you cannot use `iscntrl` for this because it is locale-specific. JSON is not about locale but unicode codepoints. 2) problem with `iscntrl` is still that of the signedness. But it is even harder to make compiler to complain about that.

Comment: If I had a time machine I'd attempt to convince IBM that EBCDIC was a poor choice.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You could use `std::iscntrl(uchar, std::locale("en_US.UTF8"))` for example.

Comment: but that won't work quite properly because the *chars* are not necessarily utf-8 codepoints.

Comment: This is a good answer. Have an upvote. The fact that it doesn’t necessarily target the OP is not an issue.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala True, it can only work for C0 control codes. C1 codes would be encoded in two code units that aren't individually control code points. A function that has to match all control codes in UTF-8 would need to deal with strings.

Comment: hmm I am actually at loss about how these C++ is-functions work. (unsigned char)0x85 => bad cast, signed char 0x85 => 0, wchar_t 0x85 => 1...